# My friend's email

Tags: cipher

Help! My friend sent me an email but it was encrypted, ciphered, or maybe it just got scrambled! I'm really curious to what it is. Can you guys help me out, please?

To: hannah@******.***

From: josh@******.***

Subject:

`Sf;!Ipx!bsf!zpv!gffmjoh@`

Body:

`Xfmm-!sfdfoumz!J(wf!cffo!fbujoh!tpnf!gjti!boe!dijqt/!Ipx!bcpvu!zpv@`

Answer (score 6):

Your friend wants to know

> Re: How are you feeling?
>  Well, recently I've been eating some fish and chips. How about you?

It's a ...

> simple substitution cipher. **!** is obviously a space and **@** a trailing punctuation mark; I assumed "." at first but found it was *?* from context.  The rest was looking at common patterns.  **f** is common, so likely *e*; **zpv** might have been *the* but it's at the end, and has no **f** for its *e* so something else - maybe *you*, which fit.  with a few letters to work with, other stuff drops into place.

Hope you enjoyed *your* lunch.

Comment: More specifically, it looks like a ROT-1 cipher with ASCII as the char-set. Didn't fully check it though.

Comment: Well, I got this using quipqiup and was about to post an answer...

Comment: lol. i didn't even realize it was rot1.  the punctuation checks out as well - it is ROT-1 on ASCII.

Comment: To help fill out the solution,
seems the email addresses are actually`@)))))).)))`.
Seriously though, I'm disappointed that voters so far
don't seem to recognize a good bite-sized puzzle.
This solution demonstrates that the puzzle is clued completely solidly.

Comment: @hannah Welcome to Puzzling! Please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/310115) this answer if it solved the question.  Also, you may want to take the [tour](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), which will help you get to know the place.  Hope to see you around :)